# How to use webpack loaders in nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, loader, nuxt.js, modernizr

I am trying to use https://github.com/itgalaxy/webpack-modernizr-loader this loader in my nuxt/webpack project.

Unfortunately loaders are added differently than with a normal webpack project and I don't really understand nuxt's documentation on this issue:

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#loaders

I have a sample repo with a minimal nuxt project:
https://github.com/Jones-S/nuxt-modernizr

In my nuxt.config.js (equivalent to webpack config)
I tried to include the loader and use in my `pages/index.vue`.

Unfortunately I am getting an error that I have modernizr not installed.
This can't be the case though.

I would be really happy if somebody could have short look into this and tell me how I correctly use loaders in nuxt.js.

For brevity my part of the nuxt.config.js

```
build: {
  /*
  ** You can extend webpack config here
  */
  extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
    // Run ESLint on save
    if (isDev && isClient) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
      })

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.modernizrrc\.js$/,
        use: { loader: 'webpack-modernizr-loader' }
      })

      config.resolve.alias['modernizr'] = '/.modernizrrc.js'

    }
  }
}
```

I am pushing the new loader and register an alias below. But I would get this error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
This dependency was not found:
* modernizr in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
To install it, you can run: npm install --save modernizr
```

thank you very much in advance.
cheers

Comment: What you want isn't the loaders stuff you linked to, you want what's a bit further up the page, "extending webpack" https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#loaders-in-extend. The one you linked to as far as I can tell is just for customizing the builtin loaders, so if you wanna add a non-nuxt handled webpack loader then you'd be extending the webpack configuration rather than handling the internal ones.

Comment: @SimonHyll Thanks for the pointer. Could you maybe make an example how to use my loader with this. It all looks so desperately different to webpack...
And if I read this, I only see an example how they change some options of the integrated loaders (looking at my link again), but not using completely new loaders...

Comment: the problem seems that webpack-modernizr-loader  dont work with vue loader, and vue loader is needed for vue files

Comment: You're adding the loader correctly, the `config` object is the Webpack `config` object so just configure that as you would normally with Webpack. As far as I've been able to gather you either haven't installed `modernizr`, you need to make `modernizr` be run before/after `vue-loader` processes `.vue` and `.js` files, or babel doesn't understand `modernizr` so you need to assist babel in understanding it, not webpack, or since you're testing with `modernizrrc\.js` it means that your `modernizrrc.js` are processed by babel, and babel doesn't understand those files.

Comment: @SimonHyll Thank you. I can follow your theory, but speaking in practical terms, I can't.
Could you maybe give me some pointers how make babel understand my stuff and how to prioritize to run modernizr?